Conservativeness of Hamiltonian versus dissipativeness of grandient
I'm reading the book Foundations of Mechanics in wich in chapter 3.3, the authors say "Skew symmetry of the symplectic form leads to conservative properties for the Hamiltonian field whereas the symmetry of a Riemannian metric leads to dissipative properties for the gradient."
And later I do not see they explaing what they mean by conservative and dissipative properties of the fields.
I'd love to have a formal intuition and also an heuristic intuition. For example, the claimed disspative properties of the gradient fields are somewhat related to the fact that such fields point out form the greater to the lesser potentials?

I'll put this into a comment since I'm not entirely sure. In the case of the Hamiltonian the "conservative" likely means that energy is conserved. Similarly, the word "dissipative" would usually imply forces like friction and viscous drag that don't conserve energy (when the generated heat is disregarded). However, I'm not sure what "dissipative" means in the context of Riemannian metrics.
